# AWS Kinesis Video Streaming with AWS Rekognition on Android App

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, video-streaming, amazon-kinesis, amazon-rekognition

I have been trying to integrate AWS Kinesis Video Stream with Rekognition in an Android app and haven't been able to get best tutorials for the same.

I want to implement Facial Recognition and I am stuck at the step of PutMedia. In the demo/documentation provided by Amazon, I found details related to **Java Producer Library and SDK** only and nothing related to Android Producer Library and SDK where I need to use Android app as Kinesis Producer and stream the video to the Rekognition service.

Is there any alternative of **PutMedia** for Android? If **yes**, what is it and how to implement it? And if **no**, how to implement PutMedia in an Android App with AWS Android Producer Library and SDK.

I have already referred the following links so far:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/rekognition/latest/dg/recognize-faces-in-a-video-stream.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/examples-putmedia.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/producer-sdk-android.html
https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonKinesisVideoDemoApp
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kinesisvideostreams/latest/dg/producersdk-android-downloadcode.html

Required Complete flow is as below:

```
1. Start video streaming on Android Device.
```

2. Detect the face from the streaming Video.

```
3. After detecting the face, match(Compare) it with already existing face from the list of images in the S3 bucket.
```

4. If the match of the face is found then return True otherwise False.

```
Any help with the issue would be a great.

Thanks
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Assuming you are streaming to Kinesis Video from camera on your Android device, you can using [AmazonKinesisVideoDemoApp](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AmazonKinesisVideoDemoApp). If you are trying to send existing video, then you would need to transcode it into MKV file and send through PutMedia
2. Write your integration similar to [kinesisvideorekognitionintegrationexample](https://github.com/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library#kinesisvideorekognitionintegrationexample) to get the output of detected faces. You will need your own logic extracting the image out similar to https://github.com/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library/blob/4d6697fb2bcf6632306ed6a36d557e268b7b7b5a/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/kinesisvideo/parser/utilities/H264BoundingBoxFrameRenderer.java#L135 . You might need AWS CLI commands in https://github.com/aws/amazon-kinesis-video-streams-parser-library/issues/75#issuecomment-555662170 to understand better if your streaming processor is working well.
3. This step might be easier to be done through adding the faces into Rekgnition face collection and then the rekgnition output from step 2 will contain information about the matching face and possibility.

Hope it helps.